# Animation works only once, OnClicked

Tags: qt, qml

I have tried to make a menu with animation but the animation works only once.
I can open it, but after I click again it won't close, like in the shown images below:
[image]

[image]

The code for the menu:

```
// The rectangle for the menu
Rectangle {
        id: menuRectangle
        width: 91
        color: "#1e1e24"
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 64
        anchors.bottomMargin: 5
        anchors.leftMargin: 5

        // Checks if the menu is open or not            
        property bool menuOut: false


        // Part of the menu            

        Column {
            id: column
            width: 90
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0

            CustomMenuBtn{
                btnIconSource: "images/settings_icon.svg"
                text: "ATTACK"
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.leftMargin: 0
                anchors.rightMargin: 0
            }
        }


        // The button that runs the animation            

        CustomMenuBtn {
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.bottomMargin: 30
            text: ""
            btnIconSource: "images/settings_icon.svg"
            onClicked: menuAnimation.running = true
        }


        //The animation

        PropertyAnimation{
            id: menuAnimation
            target: menuRectangle
            property: "width"
            to: if(menuRectangle.menuOut)
                {

                    menuRectangle.menuOut = false
                    return 91;
                }
                else
                {
                    menuRectangle.menuOut = true
                    console.log(menuRectangle.menuOut)
                    return 170;
                }

            easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint
            duration: 1000
        }
    }
```

Also, I have tried to use console.log but for some reason I can't see the output.
Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You have a binding loop on the animation's `to` property. It's value depends on `menuOut`, but it also changes `menuOut`, which would change `to`, which makes a loop.

I think it would be better to have separate open and close animations, and make sure neither one is dependent on `menuOut`. Here is one solution:

```
        CustomMenuBtn {
            onClicked: {
                if (menuRectangle.menuOut) {
                    closeAnimation.start()
                } else {
                    openAnimation.start()
                }
                menuRectangle.menuOut = !menuRectangle.menuOut
            }
        }

        PropertyAnimation{
            id: openAnimation
            target: menuRectangle
            property: "width"
            to: 170
            easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint
            duration: 1000
        }

        PropertyAnimation{
            id: closeAnimation
            target: menuRectangle
            property: "width"
            to: 91
            easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint
            duration: 1000
        }
```

Comment: What, but I change menuOut after the if(), It doesn't work like that in any other programming language I know, and it doesn't make any sense. @JarMan

Comment: It doesn't matter. The fact that it is changed within the binding itself is the problem. Try my solution. It works.

Comment: I believe you, but even if its true how does it even opens on first?

Comment: It opens the menu from the `onClicked` handler when you call `openAnimation.start()`.